# which one is the fastest method

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

I have a simple galery slider image. When the first image is visible the left arrow is hidden and when the last image is visible the right arrow is hidden.

To hide and show the arrows I used the hide and show methods. But other methods can work too, like:  fadeIn() / fade Out and css('visibility','hidden')  / css('visibility','visible')

I was wondering which is the most optmizad method. The fastest one

Thanks all

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://api.jquery.com/hide/ .hide() when not using animation.

> This is roughly equivalent to calling .css('display', 'none'), except that the value of the display property is saved in jQuery's data cache so that display can later be restored to its initial value. If an element has a display value of inline, then is hidden and shown, it will once again be displayed inline.

fadeIn() and fadeOut() use animation and will be slower and require more processing (just like hide() with a time set against it. )

Answer (score 1):

according to [**THIS TEST**](http://jsperf.com/hide-test2)- `hide()` is slightly faster then `fadeOut()` (since it doesn't use animations). but if you want the fastest way do it with native js command like `document.getElementById('a').style.display = 'none';` this is 80%-90% faster.

Comment: I don't think the test is correct. Since you hide the element the first time you execute `$("#a").hide()`, all the other statements (`$("#a").hide()`, `$("#a").fadeout()`) won't do anything. I think jQuery does some optimization and does not animate anything if the element is not visible. Also I'm not sure if you can properly benchmark these animations this way (since they are asynchronous). A better test might be http://jsperf.com/hide-test2/2, but this still does not account for the animation duration.